# Lookin for efficient and fastest way to ingest data to ADX from CSV/Parquet

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, adx, kusto-java-sdk

I have few TBs of TS data in parquet and csv files, I need to upload them to adx table is there any efficient or faster ways.

(this data ingestion is one time thing)

I tried Queued ingestion in SDK but found out the Max size of Queue is 6GB and it takes around 5min to upload 1gb data.

Comment: 1. it's not clear what you mean by "TS data" and if it's a factor in your question

Comment: @NIKHIL A V, you can try [Copy activity in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-explorer?tabs=data-factory) to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to upload your data to plain blob storage and set an [Event Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/subscribe-through-portal) "*on create*". Link the Subscription to an [Event Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-create) and connect your ADX db to this Event Hub in the Azure portal. Your data will be ingested automatically once you upload it to the blob storage.